# Android singleline marquee textview performance

Tags: android, performance

I'm using a Textview that displays marquee text. I put this textview on top of a camera preview. However, the camera preview drops like 5 fps because of the scrolling text. I've used both:

```
android:maxLines="1"
```

and

```
android:singleLine="true"
```

Which provided me with the same performance.

Is there some fix that I'm missing, if no, what would an alternative be to achieve scrolling text.